# Knockout - Upload all files one after another using a single button

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

Since I'm comparatively new to Knockout.js, which would be the best approach in Knockout to upload all files one after the other using a single button?

- Currently, the user has to click on individual `Upload` button to upload one or more files to an azure container. See `FileModel` below.
- An enhancement to this feature is to allow user to upload all files at once
  using  `Upload All Files` button. See `PageModel` below.

What I have tried so far is to iterate through each file object in the `Files =  ko.observableArray()` and upload it using its individual AJAX but that would defeat the purpose of using an AJAX call.

**PageModel**

```
var PageModel = function (r) {
    var self = this;
    this.Files = ko.observableArray();

    this.UploadAllFiles = function (e) {
        // Don't want to use this, because AJAX!
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Files(), function (file) {
            file.UploadFile();
        });
    }
}
```

**FileModel**

```
var FileModel = function (r, fileObject) {
    var self = this;
    this.FileObject = fileObject;
    this.Name = r.name;
    this.Comment = ko.observable("");

    this.UploadFile = function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('File', fileObject);
        formData.append('Comment', self.Comment());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/Action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,  
            success: function (data) {   
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
}

window.model = new PageModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

PS: There is also a manually entered string associated with every file using `data-bind="textInput : Comment"`. This additional information is also passed through with the file object in the AJAX call.

Comment: Why is looping through all the items a bad idea for ajax? I worked on a similar functionality where we upload the images immediately, and return an ID/URL then store that into the database with the `comment`.

Comment: Looping doesn't work because it does not wait for file to be uploaded and iterates to the next file. Because of this, only the last file is being uploaded, rest are not. Do you have an alternative to this?

Comment: @JohnPavek, I got an idea to make the server action as an asynchronous task so that the thread waits to finish before a new one and it worked!